# Delete using php & ajax, js from databse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

User is login and he want to delete his status.

```
<p><?php echo $status; ?></p> //this shows status
<a href="" id="<?php echo $upid; ?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

here is javascript ajax code below

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {

$(".delete").click(function(){
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var info = 'id=' + del_id;
if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",
data: info,
success: function(){
}
});
$(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
.animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
}
return false; 
});
});
</script>
```

and this is my delete.php

```
<?php 
include("includes/db_connect.php"); 

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$delete_id = $_GET['id'];

$delete_query = "delete from user_posts where upid='$delete_id'";

mysqli_query($con, $delete_query);
}

?>
```

User profile link is profile.php?id=1 This id is user ID.. not post ID.. when i move my mouse to delete button, at the bottom it shows profile id, not delete id. help me out.

http://prntscr.com/3n517j

Comment: You've either got to change your AJAX type to GET or change your PHP to work with the $_POST array. They should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to,

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$delete_id = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type: "POST",
```

change this to "GET".

Otherwise you won't find the value in $_GET.